# Do we get to keep the snowman characters after the Christmas update ends?

Tags: simpsons-tapped-out

I'm talking about the ones you win through the spinwheel, i.e. Snow God, Snow Homer, etc. They have some XP % bonus and I'm wondering if they will disappear once the snow "melts" - they are snowmen, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you win during an event you get to keep. Except for giftcards.

Comment: OK, that's good to know. The $ and XP % bonuses are nice, and I won almost everything on that wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you get to keep the snowman characters after the Christmas update ends.

When the winter event is over they 'melt down' to be just parts of the heads left. It is a visual change. Their lack of behavior and just being a visual addition to your town persists.

Unconfirmed, but I assume future winter events will restore them to their original glory for the duration of the next winter event.

Comment: Glad that we got to keep the XP / money bonuses. Loved the callback to the melted Bart snowman.